# store add - does not work

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a simple grid, which looks like so:

```
{
    xtype: "grid",
    columns: [{
        header: 'Title', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'Title'
    }],
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields:['id', 'Title']
    })
}
```

And I have a function (attached to a button) which, I believe, should populate this grid with some data. It does it like so:

```
grid.store.removeAll();
records = [{"id":"1", "Title", "Hello world"}];
grid.store.add(records);
grid.store.load();
console.log(grid.store.getCount());
```

But for some insane reason, the store is empty and `grid.store.getCount()` echoes "0". What the heck is going on? PS. I'm using ExtJS 6.

**EDIT**

If however I slightly change my code to this:

```
...
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: false,
    fields:['id','Title'],
    data:[{"id": 1,"Title": "Hello world"}]
})
...

//and in function just one line of code:
grid.store.load();
```

then it starts working. So, it seems like the whole problem is with `store.add`. It does not do what it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `grid.store.load()`.

The `load` marks the store as needing a load, but if your adding records using `add` that is not what you need.

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fbv

Comment: Oh, thank you, sir! You saved my day for a hundred time.